# Delphi TFDTable SqLite problems

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I deployed a `sample.s3db` SqLite to my Delphi android project.

1. set folder to:

   `fdconnection1.params.Database := system.ioutils.TPath.Combine( system.ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'sample.s3db');`

in FDConnection1BeforeConnect event.

2. in Project-Deployment, set folder to `assets\internal\ for Android`

However, when I run the app, apparently it can find the physical file, but it says my `tablename` "Customers" is not found.

so in the `BeforeConnect` code, if I add a CREATE TABLE SQL create code if not exists, then everything works well but of course the table is empty (whereas my deployed sample.s3db is not empty) ... which proves the FILE sample.s3db was found and not corrupted, but somehow the Table was not found.

Even tried to change in `BeforeConnect`

```
  FDConnection1.Params.Values['OpenMode'] := 'ReadWrite';
```

but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas the table name does not work?

I tried to change table name to all caps, in case Android is case-sensitive but it also does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend deleting your app from the android. This will clear out your data. Otherwise your new sqlite file is not deployed if the file already exists.  This could happen for instance if you made an error in the path at one point in time so sqlite just created an empty database.

Your connection string looks correct and so does your destination path.  Just to be safe, you may also want to clear out your other values for your connection.

fdConnection1.ConnectionDefName:= '';